# How to redirect requests to a proxy that requires authentication using firewalld?

Tags: proxy, firewalld

I have a VM running ubuntu.

The internet's access is through proxy of company, and its requiring authentication
Ex: http_proxy=http://USER:PASS@IP:3128/

I am trying, unsuccessfully, create a rule using firewall-cmd.

I want it to redirect any request to the proxy url

My code

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=proto=tcp:toport=3128:toaddr=MY_IP:user='MY_USER':passwd='MY_PASS'
```

Thanks any help